# DotCover's Coverage Tree shows only one project from solution

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, dotcover

I have a solution with three projects: a simple console application (C# startup), a class library project (C#), and a test project (F#). The tests use XUnit framework.

The problem is that no matter what I run (cover unit tests / cover current session) only the console application is visible in Coverage Tree and only the console app's code coverage is computed / shown in IDE.

I've tried toggling `match coverage results with current project structure` but it didn't make any difference (the icon at MathExpressionSolverConsoleApp changes but nothing new shows up).

[image]

**EDIT:** Ok, this is weird. When the tests are run from Continuous Testing Sessions window then all projects but the ConsoleApp one get "tested" and covered, so it basically covers the complement to what Unit Test Sessions does.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same issue.Continuous Testing shows coverage of the assemblies not shown in normal coverage report.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/34952149/2894770